# Extract message portion from logcat output (Eclipse or otherwise)

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

Anybody out there know how to copy/export just the "Message" portion of the logcat output either from Eclipse or attached via the command line?  I often need to just export the logging statements without all the timestamp, pid, and tag information as well.  For example:

```
02-25 12:35:13.083: INFO/System.out(2272): URL Requested: http://...
```

I don't need or want the `02-25 12:35:13.083: INFO/System.out(2272):` portion.  Seems like I shouldn't have to write a script to post-process the output, either.

Been driving me nuts for awhile now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run logcat from a decent shell environment (linux, osx, cygwin or msys or in a pinch use the adb shell on the device itself), and pipe it into awk or sed, probably after grepping for the category of message and PID you care about.

Comment: Ugh.  I was really hoping there was a flag somewhere I was missing in configuring adb or logcat, but in the end that will work.  Thanks.